# Cognos Report Studio If then or Case Statement that compares two different data types

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, cognos

need to find my sales/returns by G/L account and G/L Group

I keep getting the following error

For this example im trying to break about my rebuilt sales
both are in G/L Account 4100, but my rebuilt production sales have G/L Group PRODUCTION

I created a new query and put

```
if ([G/L Account] = 4100 and [G/L Group] = 'PRODUCTION') THEN ([Credit Amount] - [Debit Amount]) ELSE (0)
```

When i validate i get no errors, but when i try and view tabular data i get the following error 
An error occurred while performing operation 'sqlPrepareWithOptions' status='-126'.

I then tried this

[rebuilt_calc1]

```
[G/L Account] = 4100
```

[rebuilt_calc2]

```
CASE [rebuilt_calc1]
WHEN ([G/L Group] = 'PRODUCTION')
THEN ([Credit Amount] - [Debit Amount]) 
ELSE (0)
END
```

Is it because of tables im trying to compare? GL account and GL group?
GL account is in [Distribution Management System].[Detail Ledger].[G/L Account]
GL group is in [Distribution Management System].[Item G/L Group Master].[G/L Group]

Both are in the General Ledger Report Model

Comment: What's the rest of the error?

Comment: Thats all it tells me. The data item generates no error. Then when i try to view tabular data i says An error occurred while performing operation 'sqlPrepareWithOptions' status='-126'.DPR-ERR-2082 An error has occurred. Please contact your administrator. The complete error has been logged by CAF with SecureErrorID:2013-10-08-11:20:23.414-#2279

Comment: if i remove the "and [G/L Group] = 'PRODUCTION'" in if/then statement i can view tabular data. and all columns are filled with data.... ALSO if i remove the "[G/L Account] = 4100 and" i get data. just not with them combined

Comment: That's an extremely generic error message.  If you don't have a details link below it, you'll need to get the full error from your audit logs.

Comment: Try nesting your if clauses.

Comment: In ifuture, get the full error from the Cognos logs first and post it. That's too generic a description. Even better get your Cognos Admin to turn on client error messages so it will be displayed to you immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

if (([G/L Account] = '4100') and ([G/L Group] = 'PRODUCTION')) 
THEN ([Credit Amount] - [Debit Amount]) 
ELSE (0)

Error 126 is sometimes caused by unsupported type conversion functions, so it might be worth wrapping you expressions in cast varchar(50) to test if that's the case.  You can also check cogserver.log file in cognos_installation/logs folder, there should be detailed error  description.